# Hyperref, \noappendicestocpagenum appendix option, and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices

In my thesis, I am using both the `appendix` package and the `hyperref` package. When I get to the appendix, I use the following commands:

```
\appendix
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage
```

In the table of contents, `hyperref` is providing links on just the page numbers, using the `linktocpage=true`
option. There is no page number for the "Appendices" page displayed on the table of contents thanks to the `\noappendicestocpagenum` command; however, `hyperref` generates a small empty red box regardless. Is there a way to stop this box from forming?

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[pdftex,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter Name}
Here is my document.

\clearpage
\appendix
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage

\chapter{Appendix Name}
Here is my appendix.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would adding the option `colorlinks=true` to `hyperref` be an option for you?

Comment: Heh, that's a nice solution, but I don't think my thesis committee would appreciate the colors (even in grayscale) turning up in the print copy. I could do separate print and pdf versions, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Then perhaps use `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`.

Comment: That is one way of doing it, but I like those links being visible in the pdf copy! Note that the link to the appendix page still exists in this case however; it's just hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the use case. Package `hyperref` 6.83d will remove the link if the page number is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your instance, I would just redefine what `\addappheadtotoc` does (since you know the structure you will be working with):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%
  \phantomsection
  \addtocontents{toc}%
    {\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\appendixtocname}{}{}}%
 }
\makeatother
```

Of course, [`appendix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) is written to manage working in a variety of settings, but knowing the framework you find yourself in, it is an easy and manageable change.

Here's a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}% http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix
\usepackage[pdftex,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%
  \phantomsection
  \addtocontents{toc}%
    {\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\appendixtocname}{}{}}%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter Name}
Here is my document.

\clearpage
\appendix
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage

\chapter{Appendix Name}
Here is my appendix.

\end{document}
```